# Что нужно знать, чтобы писать под андроид на C++?

Tags: android, c++

Можно ли писать приложения под андроид не на Java, а на С++?

Что для этого нужно изучить, установить и т.д.?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Установить [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)
- Почитать [статьи](http://www.codeatcpp.com/p/android.html)
- Изучить примеры, которые идут с ndk.
- Конечно же изучить С++ и С. Как не крути, а придется их знать.
- Найти рабочий девайс, эмулятор для этого будет использовать сложнее (можно и на эмуляторе, но там не арм, и придется компилировать и под x86).
- Установить Linux или на крайний случай MacOS. Под Windows можно тоже, но несколько сложнее. А в Linux все достаточно легко. Особенно после того, как познаете Linux:)
- терпение и английский язык.

Comment: Для Code::Blocks, случайно, не настраивали? Может есть какие-нибудь линки с информацией по настройке для этой среды.

Comment: делал только в еклипсе,  а также в vim. А компилировал просто вызовом `ndk-build`.

Answer (score 4):

Еще более простой вариант - писать на VB:

http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/11/29/vb-for-android/

Правда этот конкретный продукт - платный. Зато никаких рантаймов как у Монодроида и прочих, генерит компактный APK.

Comment: писать на vb? как по мне, так это более сложный вариант.

Comment: Дело привычки конечно, но из моего опыта установка этого VB, работа в его IDE (отладка, компиляция и т.д) очень упрошают работу, по крайней мере по сравнению с Эклипсом и Явой.